# How can I access the highest and lowest price from the price scale on TradingView?

Tags: javascript, pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to access the highest and lowest values of the price scale on TradingView. I don't think it's possible but perhaps there is someone more clever than myself who has a solution.

I have looked through the Pine Script v5 reference and cannot see any available methods to access price scale data. If you dig deep into enough into the page's javascript then I think some functions might reveal the data, however I think the functions are not useable outside of their file.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't obtain the scale values directly. However you can obtain the visible highest/lowest charted values by using `chart.left_visible_bar_time` and `chart.right_visible_bar_time`

You should note that these values can not be confirmed until the script's execution reaches the final bar in the visible range. Even while iterating over historical bars Pine prohibits referencing forward data.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Time_series.html

````
//@version=5
indicator("visible high/low", overlay = true)

start_time = chart.left_visible_bar_time
end_time = chart.right_visible_bar_time

in_visible_range = time >= start_time and time <= end_time

var float hh = na
var float ll = na

if in_visible_range
    if na(hh)
        hh := high
        ll := low
    else
        hh := math.max(hh, high)
        ll := math.min(ll, low)

if time == end_time
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = high, text = "High : " + str.tostring(hh) + "\nLow : " + str.tostring(ll), style = label.style_label_lower_right)
    line.new(x1 = bar_index - 1, y1 = hh, x2 = bar_index, y2 = hh, extend = extend.both)
    line.new(x1 = bar_index - 1, y1 = ll, x2 = bar_index, y2 = ll, extend = extend.both)```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I'm already the chart method and properties from Pine Script. You can definitely retrieve the highest and lowest prices from the visible chart like that, I agree. For my purposes I need the highest and lowest values of the price scale. I agree, I don't think that's possible through Pine Script.